# How to create an EmptyField in MS Word from MS Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, qr-code

I need to insert in one excel report a QR code in which the source data is also on this excel. Due the policies of my company, I cannot use any external link or application, so Google Charts, QR code API and etc are not an option... My idea is, from the excel report make a call creating a MS Word document, add a field and using the {DISPLAYBARCODE...} controlled field, generate my QR code, returning as a picture to my Excel report. Right after the MS Word will be close without saving.

I am not a VBA master and I don't know my code is not working. I can create an open the MS Word file, paste a simple text but I can't create the field, always have the error 450 message.

```
Sub CopyToWord()

Dim doc As Object 'Word.Document

    Set doc = CreateObject("Word.Document") 'New Word.Document
    doc.Application.Visible = False 'Leave the Word document visible
    
        With doc.ActiveWindow.Selection
            doc.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="DISPLAYBARCODE xxx", PreserveFormatting:=True
            .Fields.ToggleShowCodes
           
        End With
      
      doc.Application.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a reminder, this is only the part of the code which I am struggling to do, which is add a new emptyField in MS Word.

Comment: You are using late binding so Excel does not understand Word enumerations such as `wdFieldEmpty`. You'll need to replace that with its value, -1, or, better still, set a reference to the Word object library under Tools | References and declare your variables correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Timothy, actually my library was already referred. But anyway I tried to replace wdFieldEmpty by -1 and still gets Run-Time error '450'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working across Office applications it is vital to qualify every object properly. For example: `Selection.Range` could refer to either Word or Excel. As the code is being run from Excel an unqualified reference to `Selection` will be interpreted as meaning `Excel.Selection`.

As `Selection` is a child of `Application` you also need to include an application object in your code.

```
Public Function GetWordApp(wdApp As Object) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    GetWordApp = False
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err > 0 Or wdApp Is Nothing Then
        'Word not yet open
        Err.Clear
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        If Err = 0 Then GetWordApp = True
    Else
        GetWordApp = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Sub CopyToWord()

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application, doc As Word.Document, fld As Word.Field
    
    If GetWordApp(wdApp) Then
        Set doc = wdApp.Documents.Add
        'use this if you want to do something else with the field
        Set fld = doc.Fields.Add(Range:=wdApp.Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="DISPLAYBARCODE xxx", PreserveFormatting:=True)
        fld.ShowCodes = True
        'alternative method
        'doc.Fields.Add Range:=wdApp.Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="DISPLAYBARCODE xxx", PreserveFormatting:=True
        'doc.Range.Fields.ToggleShowCodes
        wdApp.Visible = True
        wdApp.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Timothy, thanks a lot for your support. I did not implement your solution as it is, but with few adaptations it worked as I expected!!